# ReactJS / Javascript conditional statements

Tags: javascript, svg, reactjs

I am using arrow keys to move the circle object. Now I want to limit it to the height and witdth of the svg area. My conditional statements partially work as once the ball gets to any of the 'walls' it gets stuck and does not move anywhere. I understand why it does it but can't think of a way to prevent it from doing it.

Edit: CodePen: http://codepen.io/wasteland/pen/GZvWeo?editors=0110

Thanks

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    // Why you need to bind _handleKey: 
    // https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#no-autobinding
    this._handleKey = this._handleKey.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      h: 200,
      w: 800,
      x: 50,
      y: 50,
      r: 20,
      stroke: "none",
      fill: "#6F90A2"
    }
  }
  _currentPosition() {
    // Display the current position
    console.log(this.state.x, this.state.y);
  }
  
  _handleKey(e){
    // Define key codes and movement vectors
    const vector = {
     37: [-1, 0],
     38: [0, -1],
     39: [1, 0],
     40: [0, 1]
    };
    // Display the current position
    this._currentPosition()
    
    // Detect key presses and change the position accordingly
   if (e.keyCode in vector) {
        if (this.state.x < this.state.w - this.state.r &&
         this.state.x > this.state.r &&
         this.state.y > this.state.r &&
         this.state.y < this.state.h - this.state.r) {
          this.setState({
            x: this.state.x + vector[e.keyCode][0],
            y: this.state.y + vector[e.keyCode][1]  
          })   
      }
  } 
  }
   
   componentDidMount() {
     document.addEventListener("keydown", this._handleKey, false);
  }
   render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Circle { ...this.state } />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Thank you

Edit:

Following a suggestion below, I tried the following, which fails when you're in one of the four corners:

```
 if (e.keyCode in vector) {
      if (this.state.x < this.state.w - this.state.r &&
      this.state.x > this.state.r &&
         this.state.y > this.state.r &&
         this.state.y < this.state.h - this.state.r) {
        this.setState({
          x: this.state.x + vector[e.keyCode][0],
          y: this.state.y + vector[e.keyCode][1]  
        })   
      } else {
        this.setState({
          x: this.state.x - vector[e.keyCode][0],
          y: this.state.y - vector[e.keyCode][1]  
        })

      }
        }
```

Comment: One suggestion is to, once the object has hit the wall, give the object a nudge to the opposite direction to get it away from that stuck state.

Comment: I think what you need to do is, instead of checking if it **is** over the edge, check if it **will be** over the edge after the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the x and y coordinates separately. See `newX` and `newY` in `_handleKey` here: http://codepen.io/Sphinxxxx/pen/pyWYNG?editors=0010